# Opportunity product field permissions

Tags: permissions, validation-rule, permission-sets

I'm looking to give specific user access to edit single custom field on 'Opportunity Product'.
This user should not have the ability to edit any 'Opportunity' field.

I created ‘Opportunity Product’ validation rule which yields if the user change any forbidden field and I had to create ‘Opportunity’ validation rule (prevent any opportunity modification)

It seems like the 'Opportunity' and the 'Opportunity Product' both related to the same permission and when I try to edit this specific Opportunity Product field – the Opportunity validation rule yield.

And idea how to prevent this user edit opportunity but allow him edit this ‘Opportunity Product’ specific field?

The 'Opportunity Product’ validation rule:

```
AND (NOT (ISCHANGED ( my_custom_field__c )), $Profile.Name = 'Support & Automation')
```

And the 'Opportunity' validation rule:

```
$Profile.Name = 'Support & Automation'
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you paste the validation rule here?

Comment: Hi ) added in the post

Comment: As you are using profile, you can change all fields on the opportunity as read-only for the profile  'Support & Automation' from field level security, and on Opportunity Product make fields which you want editable from field level security, in this case you won't need any validation

Comment: True. I can, though I thought maybe there is more elegant solution.
instead hovering each field one by one..

Answer (score 0):

Opportunity Product has a master-detail relationship to Opportunity, so it inherits its CRUD permissions from Opportunity. You won't be able to remove object-level Edit access to the Opportunity from a user who can edit the Opportunity Product (since it's Opportunity Edit that grants the latter permission), and that means that certain standard required fields cannot be marked as read-only for this user. That list includes `Name`, `Stage`, `CloseDate`, and a handful of others.

Opportunity Product has the same basic problem - any user who has permission to edit the object at the CRUD level also gets to edit the Opportunity, Product, Quantity, and Sale Price fields.

A validation rule can only take you so far. This rule, for example,

```
AND (NOT (ISCHANGED ( my_custom_field__c )), $Profile.Name = 'Support & Automation')
```

will allow a `Support & Automation` user to make *any* change to the Opportunity Product, provided that they also change `my_custom_field__c`.

This one:

```
$Profile.Name = 'Support & Automation'
```

means that you cannot have any automation that updates the Opportunity level from the Opportunity Product level (unless it's designed very carefully and excludes updates made by these users, which won't be possible in all cases), because the rule will then fire when the programmatic update goes off.

Unfortunately, I think the only thoroughgoing solution to this ask is code-based. You'd need to completely remove Edit permission for Opportunity and Opportunity Product for these users (at the CRUD level rather than FLS) and implement some type of custom UI for the users to initiate these updates, running automation or Apex that ignores CRUD and FLS to perform the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Well since the 'Opportunity' and  'Opportunity Product' sharing the same permissions and since I would rather avoid coding here - I took [rahul gawale](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/52355/rahul-gawale) answer and added 'read only' to all 'Opportunity Product' fields (except that single field) + added the Opportunity validation rule.